# MVC Castle Windsor - can't have more than one parameter in the controller constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, castle-windsor

I set up my MVC app with Castle Windsor, from http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/543810/Dependency-Injection-and-Unit-Of-Work-using-Castle

When I have the following code, the compiler enters to the first constructor, and my services are not being initialized.

```
 private readonly IUserLoginService userLoginService;
 private readonly IUserMessageService userMessageService;

 public BaseApiController()
 {

 }

 public BaseApiController(IUserLoginService userLoginService, IUserMessageService userMessageService)
 {
     this.userLoginService = userLoginService;
     this.userMessageService = userMessageService;
 }
```

but, when I remove the 2nd parameter, the compiler enters to this (correct) constructor

```
 public BaseApiController(IUserLoginService userLoginService)
 {
     this.userLoginService = userLoginService;
 }
```

so, what can be the reason I can't add more than one parameter to my `ApiController` constructor ? All Services are in the same namespace.

container installer class:

```
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.Kernel.ComponentRegistered += Kernel_ComponentRegistered;

        //Register all controllers
        container.Register(

            //Nhibernate session factory
            Component.For<ISessionFactory>().UsingFactoryMethod(
            //CreateNhSessionFactory
                NHSessionFactoryCreator.CreateNhSessionFactory
            ).LifeStyle.Singleton,

            //Unitofwork interceptor
            Component.For<NHUnitOfWorkInterceptor>().LifeStyle.Transient,

            //All repoistories
            Classes.FromAssembly(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(NHUserLoginRepository))).InSameNamespaceAs<NHUserLoginRepository>().WithService.DefaultInterfaces().LifestyleTransient(),

            //All services
            Classes.FromAssembly(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(UserLoginService))).InSameNamespaceAs<UserLoginService>().WithService.DefaultInterfaces().LifestyleTransient(),

            //All MVC controllers
            Classes.FromThisAssembly().BasedOn<IController>().LifestyleTransient()
            );
    }
```

### edit

I see that error for `UserMessageService` (`UserLoginService` is loaded, but it has the same declaration body like `UserMessageService`)

```
Some dependencies of this component could not be statically resolved.
'Core.Services.Implementation.UserMessageService' is waiting for the following dependencies:
- Service 'Core.Repositories.IUserMessagesRepository' which was not registered.
```

Comment: Is your `IUserMessageService` definitely registered in the `IWindsorContainer`? If you put a breakpoint after the big `container.Register()` call, you can inspect `container` to check which service are registered

Answer (score 0):

I had to modify the installer class to:

```
            Classes.FromAssembly(typeof(NHUserLoginRepository).Assembly)
                   .BasedOn<IRepository>()
                   .WithService.FromInterface().LifestyleTransient(),

            Classes.FromAssembly(typeof(UserLoginService).Assembly)
                   .BasedOn<IService>()
                   .WithService.FromInterface().LifestyleTransient(),
```